# An element in $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ where $c$ is a root.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $c$ be a root of $f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 - 6x + 2.$ An element of $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $a_2c^2 + a_1c + a_0$ for some $a_2,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. If we express $c^4$ in this form, what is $a_2$?

So far i have tried creating equation $0=c^3+4c^2-6c+2$

Then $c^3 = -4c^2+6c-2$

so $c^4 = (c^3)c$

Comment: Multiply the equation by $c$ and then use it once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $c^4=(c^3)c$ you can substitute the quadratic expression for $c^3$ and get your answer.

In general for a number $c$ satisfying (irreducible) polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ any higher degree polynomial expression  $g(c)$ in $c$ can be brought down to degree less than $n$ by Euclidean division: $g(x)= q(x)f(x) + r(x)$ where the remainder will be either zero or of degree $<n$. Now substitution shows that $g(c)=r(c)$.